# Java classes and static blocks

Tags: java, static

```
class Hello12 {
    static int b = 10;
    static {
        b = 100;
    }
}

class sample {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        System.out.println(Hello12.b);
    }
}
```

On running above code the output comes as 100 because when I called Hello class, static block is executed first setting the value of b to 100 and displaying it.
But when i write this code:

```
class Hello12 {
    static {
         b = 100;
    }
    static int b = 10;
}

class sample {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        System.out.println(Hello12.b);
    }
}
```

Here the output comes as 10. I am expecting answer as 100 because once the static block is executed it gave b the value as 100. so when in main(), I called **Hello.b** it should have referred to b (=100). How is the memory allocated to b in both the codes?

Answer (score 50, accepted):

In the "Detailed Initialization Procedure" for classes, [Section 12.4.2 of the JLS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-12.html#jls-12.4.2) states:

> Next, execute either the class variable initializers and static initializers of the class, or the field initializers of the interface, **in textual order**, as though they were a single block.

This means that it's as if the first example was:

```
b = 10;
b = 100;
```

And the second example was:

```
b = 100;
b = 10;
```

The last assignment "wins", explaining your output.

Comment: @kocko That's okay. Let's help get rgettman the [Populist](http://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/62/populist) badge. Unfortunately, this means the accepted answer needs to have 10 upvotes...

Comment: Why does it compile if it's run in 'textual order'? Surely `b` hasn't been declared when it is set in the static block?

Comment: Because the compiler *like always* splits Variable DECLARATION from assignment. Like in the good old days, every Variable is first declared, a nice place in Memory is found and made cozy, before any assignments happen ;-)

Answer (score 16):

Static blocks and static variables are initialized in the order in which they appear in the source. If your code is:

```
class Hello12 {

  static int b = 10;
  static {
     b = 100;
  }

}
```

The result is 100.

Answer (score 5):

Besides answering the question of how the code is executed in what order, I am guessing you also want to know why a static block can refer to a static variable that has not been textually declared/executed yet.

While [section 12.4.2 of the JLS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-12.html#jls-12.4.2) does explain that static blocks and static variable are executed in the textual order that they appear, [section 8.3.3 of the JLS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.3.3) explains when you can reference what, and you can see that the condition of `The use is not on the left hand side of an assignment;` fails, allowing your static block in the second example to refer to a static variable that has not textually in order been declared/executed yet.

Answer (score 4):

Statics are evaluated in the order they appear in the program.